# Passing a List of Conditions to a WHERE-clause in JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

My question is very simple, really, I just want to know what boolean operator is used in the generated SQL when passing a List of Conditions to a WHERE-clause using JOOQ.

For example:

```
List<Condition> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
conditions.add(MY_TABLE.MY_COLUMN1.equal("Foo").and(MY_TABLE.MY_COLUMN2.equal("Far"));
conditions.add(MY_TABLE.MY_COLUMN1.equal("Boo").and(MY_TABLE.MY_COLUMN2.equal("Bar"));
DSL.selectFrom(MY_TABLE).where(conditions).fetch();
```

Is the resulting SQL this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE (MY_COLUMN1='Foo' AND MY_COLUMN2='Far') OR (MY_COLUMN1='Boo' AND MY_COLUMN2='BAR');
```

or this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE (MY_COLUMN1='Foo' AND MY_COLUMN2='Far') AND (MY_COLUMN1='Boo' AND MY_COLUMN2='BAR');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions are `AND`-connected. While the Javadoc on `SelectWhereStep.where(Condition...)` doesn't mention this ([which should be fixed](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3847)), the underlying implementation is that of [`SelectQuery.addConditions(Condition...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectQuery.html#addConditions-org.jooq.Condition...-), which specifies usage of [`Operator.AND`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Operator.html#AND).

So the resulting query will be your second example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE (MY_COLUMN1='Foo' AND MY_COLUMN2='Far') 
  AND (MY_COLUMN1='Boo' AND MY_COLUMN2='BAR');
```